# How to write a default parameter callback function that does nothing? [Python]

Tags: python, callback, default-parameters

I sometimes want to pass in a callback function as a parameter to `my_function`. However, I want the default behavior to simply do nothing.

I find myself wanting to write the following **invalid** lines of code:

```py
def my_function(args, callback_function=pass):
    # do something
    callback_function()
```

But that doesn't work, so the best **valid** solution I have come up with is:

```py
def do_nothing():
    pass

def my_function(args, callback_function=do_nothing):
    # do something
    callback_function()
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, more like the first example above?

Comment: if you control `my_function` it would be pretty reasonably to simply check `if callback_function: callback_function()`

Comment: But if you don't want to do that, then what you have now is pretty clean as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling 'None' should do what you're asking. 'pass' is a keyword and is not callable like that. None is a default value and can be applied using lambda.

```
 def my_function(args, callback_function=lambda: None):
        # do something
        callback_function()
```

Comment: I actually think this is *less clean* than what the OP has.

Comment: Yes, including the if statement like in the other answer might be the more 'correct' way of accomplishing OPs requirement. This was just an attempt to keep the theme of a oneliner like was mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You might elect to accept `None` and only call `callback_function` when it is not `None`, that is

```
def my_function(args, callback_function=None):
  # do something
  if callback_function is not None:
      callback_function()
```